# Extraindo infos de um JSON externo por php

Tags: php, json

```
<?php
  $json = "https://graph.facebook.com/264449740579494?access_token=EAACFJ0t0JZAMBAHQYJ1f1DuWZBVmS9FyUKPGIzAqVO9z8EqdFLw0SqZB7E7mDzKiLfHdmHaivO5lwOuU7MZAhmz2810rwRy85IGMwfZAPtSNYEypfgfW9uIIA5tXJS5qSZCjk5YnFg9iXUGPKc0lNXZAgXqirfCA8gJ1hQa2VQ9hhAGlp0ooFYmr2ykws7jebktYIYwtsYNKAZDZD&fields=fan_count";
  $json = var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
  echo $json['fan_count'];
?>
```

Como faço pra extrair desse json o número do "fan_count"? Ele só retorna NULL

Comment: Primeiro, você precisa fazer uma requisição HTTP para obter o JSON de retorno. Por enquanto você está tentando analisar uma URL como se fosse JSON. Segundo, precisaremos saber a estrutura do JSON retornado para dizermos como acessar o valor desejado.

Comment: Nesse caso o simples pode sair caro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma solução simples é usar file_get_contents

```
<?php
$json = "https://graph.facebook.com/264449740579494?access_token=EAACFJ0t0JZAMBAHQYJ1f1DuWZBVmS9FyUKPGIzAqVO9z8EqdFLw0SqZB7E7mDzKiLfHdmHaivO5lwOuU7MZAhmz2810rwRy85IGMwfZAPtSNYEypfgfW9uIIA5tXJS5qSZCjk5YnFg9iXUGPKc0lNXZAgXqirfCA8gJ1hQa2VQ9hhAGlp0ooFYmr2ykws7jebktYIYwtsYNKAZDZD&fields=fan_count";
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($json), true);
echo $json['fan_count'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando [curl](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php), [sendo uma biblioteca para comunicação de diversos servidors e também diversos protocolos](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.curl.php), é baixado o conteúdo desse endereço no formato `json`:

```
{
   "fan_count": 185,       
   "id": "264449740579494"
}
```

e com a função [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php) que decodifica uma string JSON para um `array` associativo ou um objeto conforme configuração no seu segundo parâmetro, exemplo:

```
<?php

    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/264449740579494?access_token=EAACFJ0t0JZAMBAHQYJ1f1DuWZBVmS9FyUKPGIzAqVO9z8EqdFLw0SqZB7E7mDzKiLfHdmHaivO5lwOuU7MZAhmz2810rwRy85IGMwfZAPtSNYEypfgfW9uIIA5tXJS5qSZCjk5YnFg9iXUGPKc0lNXZAgXqirfCA8gJ1hQa2VQ9hhAGlp0ooFYmr2ykws7jebktYIYwtsYNKAZDZD&fields=fan_count';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $json = curl_exec($ch);    
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ($httpCode == 200)
    {
        $array = json_decode($json, true);
        echo $array['fan_count'];
    }
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: beleza, usando esse curl funcionou.